# MySQL installation stuck on debian

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, server, debian

I am following this guide to install mysql on debian [how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-debian-10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-debian-10).
However, i'm stuck on this screen
[image]

I tried clicking ok and pressing enter nothing happned.
Restarted the device still same thing.

Comment: Press the tab and then it will highlight `<OK>` then press Enter.

Comment: Added an answer from the comment. You can accept it so if others have a similar issue they can get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the screen has a `<Ok>` button but it's not highlighted, so without that if you press `Enter`, it will do nothing. This is how the GUI works on the console.

`Use tab to highlight <Ok> button and then press Enter`.